# Sqlite Like query xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a like in xamarin, but what the query returns to me is just a number, I already tested it in DBowser sqlite, and it works, but not here.
What will be the mistake?

**Query**

```
public Task<Produtos> GetProdutosAsyncBy(String searchField)
{
    string searchNoSpaces = searchField.Replace(" ", "%");
    var get_docnumb = database.ExecuteScalarAsync<Produtos>("SELECT *" +
                      " FROM Produtos WHERE Design LIKE '%" + searchNoSpaces + "%'");

    return get_docnumb;   
}
```

**Call Query**

```
public async void SearchProdutoQuery ()
{
    var qwe = App.Database.GetProdutosAsyncBy(searchBar_produtos.Text).Result;
}
```

Comment: That is what execute scalar does - it returns one value, the first column of the first row of the first result set.

Comment: Because you are using ExecuteScalar. That is good you had that error because your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Instead of string concatenation use parameters.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes I know, This is an test, but the error is because im not using parameters?

Comment: Nope, already said it was because you are asking for a single value using ExecuteScalar. Try using ExecuteDbDataReader or ExecuteReader instead. IMHO it would be easier to use Linq.

Comment: @CetinBasoz But SQLiteAsyc dose not contain ExecuteReader or ExecuteDbDataReader

Comment: Can I use Queryasync? @CetinBasoz

Comment: Probably, I am not using that namespace. Check documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Scalar to return something as below:

```
public int GetCountProdutosAsyncBy(String searchField)
{

    string searchNoSpaces = searchField.Replace(" ", "%");
    var get_docnumb = database.ExecuteScalarAsync<Produtos>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Produtos WHERE Design LIKE '%" + searchNoSpaces + "%'");

    return get_docnumb;

}
```

But to solve your problem you can't use Scalar, you need to QUERY and to avoid SQL injection you should use parameter:

```
public Task<Produtos> GetProdutosAsyncBy(String searchField)
{

    string searchNoSpaces = searchField.Replace(" ", "%");
    var get_docnumb = database.Query<Produtos>("SELECT * FROM Produtos WHERE Design LIKE ?", "%" + searchNoSpaces + "%");

    return get_docnumb;

}
```